# Running a script from a powershell script with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

So, I have a script I use for deployments and some of these commands aren't recognized till after sqlps is run, usually I do it manually. I want to automate the running of that script. Here is the script:

```
    $client = Read-Host "Enter Client name"
    $date = Get-Date -Format "yymmdd"
    $sqlsrvname = Read-Host "Please enter the sql server name"
    $deploytype = Read-Host "Is there a server instance? (1) Yes (2) No"


   switch($deploytype){

   1 {$Instance = Read-Host "Please Enter instance name" 
    cd -Path $ppath
    Invoke-Command .\sqlpatchremote.ps1 -DBServer $sqlsrvname –dbinstance $Instance –client $client –mainline HTFS –datefolder $date –targetenv $sqlsrvname } 

 2 {cd -Path $ppath
 Invoke-Command .\sqlpatchremote.ps1 –dbs $sqlsrvname –client $client –mainline HTFS –datefolder $date –targetenv $sqlsrvname }

 default {"Invalid Selection"}

}
```

When I try to run this script I get this error:

```
Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DBServer'.
At line:17 char:38
+  Invoke-Command .\sqlpatchremote.ps1 -DBServer $sqlsrvname –dbinstance $Instance 
...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindi 
   ngException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
   InvokeCommandCommand
```

It tells me its an invalid command when it normally works when I type this in manually, how can I make this work? This script is suppose to install SQL databases on a SQL server. When I run this code manually I just type "sqlps" and then navigate to the directory of the script. Then I run it with the filled in parameters and it doesn't give me an error. I feel like this might be a simple fix to get this to work, but I'm not sure what it is and I wasn't really sure how to ask it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error:

```
Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DBServer'.
At line:17 char:38
```

`Invoke-Command` rejects parameter `DBServer`. This means you are passing the arguments to `Invoke-Command` instead of your script.

To pass the arguments to the script you are invoking, you have to use the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Try :

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "targethost" .\sqlpatchremote.ps1 -ArgumentList "-DBServer $sqlsrvname –dbinstance $Instance –client $client –mainline HTFS –datefolder $date –targetenv $sqlsrvname"
```

**EDIT:** really not sure about the above syntax for the arguments :( (if anyone could confirm?)

With the arguments in the proper order I've successfully tested it like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "targethost" "scriptpath" -ArgumentList $arg1,$arg2#,...
```

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)

Comment: yeah i tried what you said and this happened:      `Invoke-Command :                   Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named 
parameters.
At line:7 char:2
+  Invoke-Command .\sqlpatchremote.ps1 -ArgumentList "-DBServer $sqlsrvname –dbins 
...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindi 
   ngException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.I 
   nvokeCommandCommand`

Comment: If you are only running the script locally, just use `. .\sqlpatchremote.ps1` followed by the arguments for the script. You don't need `Invoke-Command`

Comment: either way as i stated in my previous comment, i tried what you told me and it did not work unfortunately =/

Comment: is there anyway i should specially identify the variables in the arguments? i tried it and it doesnt seem to be detecting the variables values.

Comment: i got this error: `Please specify a target environment
At C:\SQLPatchRemote.ps1:8 
char:32
+     [String] $TargetEnv    = $(throw, "Please specify a target environment"),
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [], Runt 
   imeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Please specify a target environment`

Comment: Sorry I mixed calling the script and including it (with the dot). Does this work ? `.\sqlpatchremote.ps1 -DBServer $sqlsrvname –dbinstance $Instance –client $client –mainline HTFS –datefolder $date –targetenv $sqlsrvname`

Comment: yes it worked thank you! (took me a while to have the chance to test it lol)